# Issue with pycharm:(Pycharm:Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams)

Tags: python, pycharm

I just started to us Python and Pycharm today. I installed Python 3.4.3 and pycharm 4.5, and I'm using Windows 7 OS on a acer TravelMate 8471 laptop.

When I try to print("hello"), the error is:

> "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
>   LookupError: unknown encoding: x-windows-950"

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Whats your file name? maybe it shadows a built-in module.

Comment: i Change all kind of different file and still doesn't work

Comment: Please tell us about your computer's locale settings.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the hello.py file in a subdirectory of your project directory.

All the files in the project directory essentially provides relevant "system information" of the project. One project may contains couple of applications. Each application should be put in one subdirectory.

set:
"Settings/Editor/File Encodings/Project Encoding"
to:
"UTF-8"

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the [PY-15481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15481) bug. Try [PyCharm 4.5.1 RC build](http://eap.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: I reinstall the Pycharm and reboot everything. But when i try to run something it still show the same error

Comment: @Ryan1339 Have you installed PyCharm 4.5.1 RC?